# how to open file in server using vb6

Tags: vb6

i have file in my testserver. In my code i have to read that txt file which is located in test server. how to create path to that file which is in server using my code in vb6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use some kind of config file to tell you where this file is? Or a database METADATA entry. How do you know where your server is? If you have a staic link to that, it could help.

This link should give you a very good idea of how to open, read a text file line by line

[Reading a Text file Line by Line](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet318.htm)

Now all you need to try, is using your path, to see if you have access to the fille, and if you can reach it.

Comment: this is where i have my file

"\\PSGSPHX02\NORS\Rs\ClientUpdate\"

Answer (score 1):

You Need a Internet transfer control...

Code:

```
Dim txt As String
txt = Inet1.OpenURL ("[PATH]")
```

'you got the file in txt << string : )   this works on text files!!!!